# Pintool For OSX

Tags: dynamic-analysis, osx

I see that PinTool works for Windows and Linux.  Does it also happen to work for OSX?  Or is there a similar tool that I can use to easily record code coverage for a closed-source app?

Comment: dtrace is a really nice tool that OS X has. It's a bit inefficient to instrument at the "every instruction" level, but it lets you instrument all kinds of system calls and such. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtrace.1.html

Comment: Your question can be easily answered by 5 seconds of googling, no?

Comment: @newgre I was hoping for experiences with it, as joxeankoret points out a good one to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, pintool works on os x as well (Snow Leopard or newer for the current tech preview ver).

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pintool-downloads

Comment: pintool does not seem to be available anymore on OSX.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they work as @broadway already pointed out. However, PIN under OSX have many-many restrictions, some of them documented and others not. The most noticeable feature it lacks is support for creating threads in a PIN tool.